# Error.There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'CategoryId'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

am getting error below view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control edited" })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The ViewData item that has the key 'XXX' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Comment: Because the value of `CategoryId` is `null`, either because you did not set it in the GET method, or you did not reassign it in the POST method before returning the view.

Answer (score 0):

Because you apply selectList as null in the DropDownList. below line will help you.

```
@Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", (new List<SelectListItem>()), "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control edited" })
```

it is just example you need to pass object of **List<< SelectListItem >>()** if it blank the pass that object with no items.